# Minimum distribution of random walk for $p > \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a Markov Chain defined on the integers. Suppose $P_{n,n+1}=p$ and $P_{n,n-1}=1-p$, with $p > \frac{1}{2}$. Assume $X_{0}=0$.

What is the distribution of $\min\{X_{0}, X_{1}, \dots, \}$?

Comment: Oops, I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m_k=P(Y=-k)$ for $k\geq 0$. Then $m_k$ satisfies the following recurrence:

$$m_k=pm_{k+1}+(1-p)m_{k-1}$$

Solving it subject to condition $\sum_{k\geq 0} m_k=1$ yields $$m_k=\big(1-\frac{1-p}p\big)\big(\frac {1-p}p\big)^k$$

**ETA:** To show that the above condition is satisfied, we need to show that $Y$ is finite a.s. This follows from the fact that $X_n\to \infty$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Why do we consider negative values of $k$?

Comment: Values of $\min$ are non-positive since we start at 0, so I introduce $k=-\min$ just for the convenience of working with non-negative indices,

Comment: Should that be $m_{k-1}$ instead of $m_{m-1}$?

Comment: Why the recurrence? (Apparently the OP knows since the answer is accepted...)

Comment: Consider a single step from $X_0=0$. With probability $p$ it goes up and is $k+1$ steps away from $-k$ level; with probability $1-p$ it goes down and is $k-1$ steps away from $-k$ level.

Comment: But $m_0\ne pm_1$.

Comment: Recurrence holds for $k\geq 1$.